# Are BCM2711's CPUs always running in 'secure' world?

Tags: pi-4, hardware, arm

If SoC's don't use TrustZone, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16821526/22309586) it means that the CPU starts in the 'secure' world but does not change to the 'normal' one. Is this the case with the Raspberry Pi 4's BCM2711? In the [forums](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1796617#p1796599) they say there is no support, so this looks like it.

Comment: There's no support of Trustzone in either 32-bit or 64-bit booting of your RPi ARM processor. That piece of hardware is not enabled (don't think it's even available on the RPi hardware).

Comment: @Dougie So this means that internally the CPUs are always NS=0?

Comment: You should be able to assume that.